# Как перенсти текст внутри flex элемента

Tags: html, css

Доброе время суток. Есть простая верстака на flex-box

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.6em;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  position: relative;
}
.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.one {
  background: #508694;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.two {
  background: #BB844C;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
.three {
  background: #929D79;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item one">Some block</div>
  <div class="flex-item two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="flex-item three">Some block</div>
</div>
```

Как сделать чтоб при респонсе текст внутри блока переносился когда достигает края родительского блока, а не когда упирается в край экрана?

**Возможно не совсем корретно изначально описал задачу.**

При адаптиве (респонсе) пока у блока с текстом есть свободное простанство все норм http://joxi.ru/n2YegBqIb6zxY2, а когда текст уже не помещается в блоке, вся верстка начинает выпадать из родителя http://joxi.ru/82QZBMxIwvxewA. Возможно тут вообще нужно другое решение и на чистом css это не реализовывается.

Comment: Pri kakom "респонсе"? Что-то не пойму о чем речь. Если развернуть верстку Вашу на весь экран - всё работает как надо и текст не покидает отведённый ему блок.

Comment: Респонс имеется ввиду изменени ширины экрана.

Comment: вы уберите фиксированную ширину и текст сам перенесётся

Comment: можно поставить padding какой не будь

Comment: Поповоду фиксированной ширины согласен, но проблемы это не решает http://joxi.ru/E2pzELNh7MNJ7r

Comment: может это поможет white-space: pre-wrap;

Comment: К сожалению не помогло.

Comment: а !important пробывали ?

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: @VadimX вы хотите сделать перенос по буквам в блоке, или что? Я могу это сделать в своём ответе, если вам нужно

Comment: Ничего не понятно. И картинки надо загружать в вопрос - не могу их открыть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Флексы не подходят для того, чтобы ими управлять как сеткой(для этого создали гриды), нужно использовать их преимущество - они очень удобно изменяются во флексовом контейнере

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 max-width: 900px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 26px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.one, .two > div, .three > div {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
}

.two, .three {
 flex: 1;
}

.two__One {
 flex: 1;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.one {
  height: auto;
 flex: 2;
 background-color: red;
}

.two {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.two > div {
 background-color: gold;
}

.three > div {
 background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="one">Super TSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Textext</div>
 <div class="two__One">
  <div class="two">
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
   <div>SuperSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text Text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вариант рабочий, но не совсем подходит, т.к. нужно использовать дополнительную обертку в разметке.

Comment: @VadimX если вам хочется меньше разметки, вам придётся изучить гриды

Comment: @ Михаил Камахин - понято, Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

**Коментарии добавлены в коде**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item one">Some block</div>
        <div class="flex-item two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
        <div class="flex-item three">Some block</div>
    </div>
    <style>
            .flex-container {
                display: flex;
                /*width: 750px;*/ /* 1. Убираем фиксированную ширину родителю */
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: 300px;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 2.6em;
                flex-flow: column wrap;
                position: relative;
            }
            .flex-item {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .one {
                background: #508694;
                margin-right: 10px;
                flex-basis: 100%;
            }
            .two {
                background: #BB844C;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                flex: 1 1 0;

                /* 2. Добавляем свойства */
                white-space: pre-wrap;
                word-break: break-word;
                padding-right: 217px; /* ширина левого (первого) блока. Динамически можно посчитать через js */
            }
            .three {
                background: #929D79;
                flex: 1 1 0;
            }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Задачу с переносом текста решаем но основная проблема остается.